# Cascading img width

Tags: css, image

I have a general css for all img and there is a specific img that is different. I give an id to that different img, but nothing changes.

I can solve that giving a class to all the other img but I want to understand why it is not enough just with the general #div img css?. So the question is why #content img does not work?
What are the rules in the cascade in this case?

Here is the example very simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/GTqgP/5/

CSS

```
#content img { width:200px; }
#second { width:100px; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="content" >    
<img id="first" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" />
<img id="second" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about your rules, you need to have a more specific rule if you want the `second` ID to take precendence,

add

```
#content #second { width:100px; }
```

You could also do

```
#second { width:100px !important; }
```

But `!important` shouldn't really be necessary are needed if you have a more specific rule for applying different styles to that ID

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration for `second` is wrong.  It should be

```css
#second { width: 100px; }
```

**EDIT:** re: the updated question.  Although it should work (in my opinion), for some reason it doesn't.  However you can use `!important` qualifier to get it to work:

```css
#second { width: 100px !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the # on "second"s identification on your css.

It should be:

```css
#second { width:100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
http://jsfiddle.net/GTqgP/
```

html

```
<img id="first" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" />
<img class="second" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" />
```

CSS

```
img { width:200px; }
.second { width:100px; }
```